# How to run an exe file using java script at runtime

Tags: javascript, protractor, autoit

I am trying to automate some stuff using protractor. I have a situation where I need to deal with a Windows pop-up and I have an AutoIt script compiled (.exe) for this. I could import this at runtime in Java and selenium. I am not sure how to do that in Protractor and JavaScript case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open external files, then you should use the **built-in** `child_process` module.

```js
var { exec } = require("child_process");
//the function acts like a shell, so just use shell commands.
exec("cmd.exe");
```

Comment: Thank your. Does it work on windows? I tried both exec and execFile but it did not work. i.e. exec("C:\file.exe");

Comment: Yes. It should work on every os as far as I know. Worked for me, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try NPM package/l [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs)

Example:

```
// Run external tool synchronously
if (shell.exec('git commit -am "Auto-commit"').code !== 0) {
  shell.echo('Error: Git commit failed');
  shell.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting the use of an external tool instead of built-in modules, like `child_process`?